# Jupyter Notebook's search and replace not as greedy as regex101's javascript

Tags: regex, jupyter-notebook

I have a number of `logger.*()` functions I want to convert to simple `print()` statements in a Jupyter Notebook. I already changed the beginning of the lines: `logger.*(`. Now I need to fix the tail and change `", e` to `" % (e`:

```
print("(%s):\n"
        "    Failed to load logger" % (e, ))

logger.error("(%s):\n"
        "    Validation Testing errors occurred. '%s'",
        e, report_file)

logger.critical("(%s):\n"
        "    Failed to return Parsed Report "
        "    in debug mode.", e)

logger.critical("(%s):\n"
        "    Error loading template.", e)
```

Using Regex101 to test my javascript Regex, I wrote

```
print\("[\s\S.]*(", e)
```

But in Jupyter's find and replace, this only captures up to `print("(%s)\n"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search and replace preview shows only a single line. Nonetheless, regex replace works across multiple lines. Your sample string can be replaced as suggested:

```
print\("[\s\S]*?", e\)
```

While the dialog shows 0 matches the replacement works anyway:

[image]

Note: I've modified your search pattern. The modified dot should match lazy, `[\s\S]*?` to avoid matching too much. Also, I removed the capture group, it looks like you do not need it.

---

**Update**: As it turned out the capture group needed to be inverse to replace the string in question (kudos to xtian):

Search:

```
(print\("[\s\S.]*)", e
```

Replace:

```
$1 " % (e,
```

Comment: I'm replacing the start and end of a logger with print statements. The start is easy, but the end has common syntax and returns false matches. I need to change the matching ends conditioned on it being a print statement. Curiously, you're right about the match count. Despite showing 0 results, the search did match and correct, but only once and it deleted the rest of the file. haha. So Jupyter fails at multi-line matching and blows up when the match count is 0. weird!

Comment: @xtian I could do multiple multiline replacements. Have you used a lazy match operator as suggested? Please show more of your sample input, if you need help.

Comment: Oh! If you don't use *lazy* then the match skips to the end. With lazy, you get the multiple matches. For some reason I thought lazy only found the first match. I get it. Now with the lazy fix, I see the capture group needed to be inverse, Search: `(print\("[\s\S.]*)", e`; Replace: `$1 " % (e,`. If you update your answer, I'll mark it as correct--you have everything else. One, I didn't get the power of *lazy*, and two 0 results ain't zero.